# Reading greek letters from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a .csv file with a certain number of columns. One of the column has several values called `Δ` (Greek letter Delta).

I tried to print the letter and I was successful:

```
print u'\u0394'
```

properly returns the Greek letter.

However, if I try to select the rows of the file containing `Δ` in the column called `'column'`, using

```
file=pd.read_csv('filename.csv',sep=';')
print file[file['column']==u'\u0394']
```

I find myself with an empty list, even though I know that some rows do have `Δ` in that column.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `file['column']` may be a UTF-8 encoding of U+0394, rather than the Unicode code point itself. `print "\xce\94"` will output (terminal allowing) the character Δ, but `"\xce\94" == u'\0394'` is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add `encoding='utf-8'` to read_csv, because python 2 does not default to unicode strings (and byte strings can't deal with Delta). You don't get anything because Pandas silently ignores the failure when reading the string:

```
file=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```